# Convert list of list into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of list as follows

```
my_list = [['val1','12'],['val2', 'disabled'],['apple', 10],['banana', 20]]
```

i would like to convert my_list into dictionary such that my_dict looks like

```
my_dict = {'val1':'12','val2':'disabled','apple':10, 'banana:20}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just issue `dict(my_list)`. The `dict` constructor accepts any iterable of two-element iterables.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own code like:

```
my_dict = {}

for i in my_list:
    my_dict[i[0]] = i[1]

print(my_dict)
```